# React useState converting valid dynamic object into NaN values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hooks

I am importing from a time series database that returns the amount of milliseconds that an object has been in different states in the course of an hour. The data looks like below.

```
{
  id: mejfa24191@$kr,
  timestamp: 2023-07-25T12:51:24.000Z,
  // This is the field that is dynamic
  meta: {
    active: 360000,
    stopped: 710000,
    idle: 0,
    etc.
  }
}
```

I want to some all these values for each hour to get the total time for each field. To do this I check when a new hour has been found and take the values from the previous entry since that would be the entry from the top of the previous hour.

I'm having an issue where I am able to create a valid object with the total time from the previous hour but whenever I set this to a state variable it turns the valid object into one where each number is NaN.

I am currently trying to use a deep copy to set the state. Originally I tried doing it in the for loop using function to set as such `setTotalHours((prev) => ({...prev, [key]: totalHours[key] + currHourTotal[key]}))`.

Here is the code:

```
const [totalHours, setTotalHours] = useState<{[key: string]: number}>({});
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading) {
      let currHourTotal: { [key: string]: number } = {};
      let currHour = new Date(hours[0].timestamp).getUTCHours();
      for (const h of hours) {
        if (new Date(h.timestamp).getUTCHours() !== currHour) {
          if (h.meta) {
            const total = cloneDeep(totalHours);
            for (const key in h.meta) {
              total[key] = total[key]
                ? total[key] + Number((currHourTotal[key] / (1000 * 60 * 60)).toFixed(2))
                : Number((currHourTotal[key] / (1000 * 60 * 60)).toFixed(2));
            }
            console.log('Total Deep Copy', total);
            setTotalHours(total);
            console.log('Total State', totalHours);

          }
          currHour = new Date(h.timestamp).getUTCHours();
        } else if (new Date(h.timestamp).getUTCHours() === currHour) {
          if (h.meta) {
            for (const key in h.meta) {
              currHourTotal[key] = h.meta[key];
            }
          }
        }
      }
      const total = cloneDeep(totalHours);
      for (const key in currHourTotal) {
        total[key] = total[key] + currHourTotal[key] / (1000 * 60 * 60);
      }
      setTotalHours(total);
    }
  }, [loading, hours]);
```

and if I look at the logs that are listed from above it looks like this.

[Logs from run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57cBj.png)

I have tried using function setting such as `setTotalHours((prev) => ({...prev, [key]: prev[key] + currHourTotal[key]}))` and other ways but everything I have attempted has resulted in this failure.

This is driving me nuts so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it specifically the use of state which produces this result?  Or is the result produced in the object itself *before* saving that object to state?  When you debug the code shown, which specific operation *first* produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I think that `currHourTotal[key]` is probably undefined when you try to use it within `for (const key in h.meta)`.  You could log it to verify.

Comment: @James logs show a value every time it loops. If you look at the logs I added it shows that the "total" object is being filled which is coming from currHourTotal[key]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach that uses a reducer to calculate the "total" object.

```js
const hours = [
{
  id: "mejfa24191@$kr",
  timestamp: "2023-07-25T12:51:24.000Z",
  // This is the field that is dynamic
  meta: {
    active: 360000,
    stopped: 710000,
    idle: 0
  }
},
{
  id: "mejfa24191@$ks",
  timestamp: "2023-07-25T12:51:24.000Z",
  // This is the field that is dynamic
  meta: {
    active: 360000,
    stopped: 710000,
    idle: 0,
    somethingElse: 200
  }
},
{
  id: "mejfa24191@$kt",
  timestamp: "2023-07-25T13:51:24.000Z",
  // This is the field that is dynamic
  meta: {
    active: 360000,
    stopped: 710000,
    idle: 0,
    other: 200
  }
}
];

const total = hours.reduce((acc, el) => {
  const h = new Date(el.timestamp).getUTCHours();
  if (!acc[h]) {
    acc[h] = {...el.meta};
  } else {
    Object.keys(el.meta).forEach(key => {
      if (!acc[h][key]) 
        acc[h][key] = el.meta[key];
      else
        acc[h][key] += el.meta[key];
    });
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(total);
```